# Is there Phonegap plugin for modules purchase?

Tags: cordova, app-store, google-play

I want to make free application based on Phonegap with the possibility to by premium module on Play Market for Android & App Store for IOS. How can I do this? Maybe there is a special plugin for Phonegap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [iOS](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/InAppPurchaseManager) and [Android](https://github.com/poiuytrez/AndroidInAppBilling) plugins for those to help you out.

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented the iOS In-App Purchase plugin. 
Unfortunately haven't found single plugin for both.

https://github.com/j3k0/PhoneGap-InAppPurchase-iOS